# Integrate $\int\frac{dx}{7+5\cos x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

$$\int\frac{dx}{7+5\cos x}$$

I'm stuck in this problem plzz give some clue to solve this problem

If I will write numerator as $~\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x=1~$

Then it become more complex

Please tell me an approach  how to tackle this one

Answer (score 5):

Integrals of this form are normally easily solved using the [Tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution):
$$t=\tan\frac x2$$
$$dx=\frac 2{1+t^2}dt$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
so this would give you:
$$\int\frac{dx}{7+5\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{1}{7+5\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt=\int\frac{2}{7(1+t^2)+5(1-t^2)}dt$$
Now you should be able to solve it

Comment: You say "easily" here.  My experience with the Weierstrass substitution: if there is any other way to do the integral, it will be easier than the Weierstrass substutution.

Comment: @GEdgar As sad as it may be Weirerstrass substitution is a necessary reality for most non-elementary solvable integrals.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int\frac{dx}{7+5\cos x}=\int \frac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2\left(\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+6\right)}~dx$$

putting $~u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}~\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)~$, we have
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}~\int \frac{du}{u^2+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}~\tan^{-1}u+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}~\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}~\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+C$$
where $~C~$ is constant.

---

we have $$\cos 2a=\frac{1-\tan^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the so-called Weierstrass substitution:
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized approach to such kinds of integrals;

$$I_1=\int \frac{1}{a+b(cosx)} \,dx$$ and $$I_2=\int \frac{1}{a+b(sinx)} \,dx$$

We can substitute;  $tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=t$ and  $\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}=dx$.

Moreover, $cosx=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ for $I_1$ and $sinx=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ for $I_2$.

Let, $$I(a,b)=\int \frac{1}{a+b(cosx)} \,dx$$

$$I(a,b)=2\int \frac{1}{(a+b)+t^2(a-b)} \,dt$$

$$I(a,b)=\frac{2}{(a-b)} \int \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}\right)^2+t^2}\,dt$$

Hint : $\int \frac{1}{a^2+t^2}\,dt=\frac{1}{a} arctan\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)+c$

$$I(a,b)=\frac{2}{\left(\sqrt{{(a+b)}{(a-b)}}\right)} arctan\left(\frac{t}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}\right)}\right)+c$$

$$I(a,b)=\frac{2}{\left(\sqrt{{(a+b)}{(a-b)}}\right)} arctan\left(\frac{tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}\right)}\right)+c$$

For $(a,b)=(7,5)$;

We get, $$I(7,5)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}~\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}~\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+c$$

Similarly, you can generalize $I_2$.

**Note** - $a,b ∈ Z$ and c is integration constant.